# Left join without returning NA values

Tags: r, join, left-join

I am using R and the library `dplyr`.

I want to join a larger database with a smaller database (in terms of rows).

I use left join because I want to have a final database that has the same number of rows as the larger one.

This naturally returns `NA` values when the smaller database does not have a value corresponding to the joining key.

What I want to achieve is sort of copying the previous values of the smaller database into the rows where `NA` is returned by the left join.

In other words:

```
if is.na(columnvalue[j]) == TRUE then 
    columnvalue[j] = columnvalue[j-1]
```

where `columnvalue` is a joined column from the smaller database and `j = 1,..., nrow(largerdataset)`.

A loop with that if statement should work, but it is a bit cumbersome. Is there any other smarter solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show some sample data and expected output please?

Comment: Without having a look on sample/example, I am not sure, but it seems you want sort of `zoo::na.locf()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update with some sample data, I could provide full code for this. The general solution is to use `fill` from `tidyr` package, possibly with a `group_by` the key if needed. You would just write it as:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  # group_by(key) %>%
  tidyr::fill(var1, var2, var3, .direction = "up")
```